# Delete pdb files from MySql bin folder

Tags: mysql

I have MySql 5.5 installed on 2008R2 x64 server and notice that installation folder size is more that 500MB. In a bin folder almost every exe contains .pdb file. Is it possible to delete those files?

**Update** I have used installer Change and marked Debug binaries and Debug Symbols to be not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Those are debugging symbols, and are only really necessary if you wish to produce some type of debug information from MySQL.